# How to refresh a nix derivation (nix pill's 7.5) in nix-repl?

Tags: nix

Looking at the example given in [the 7th nix pill](https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/working-derivation.html#idm140737316336848), typing `:b simple` builds the derivation for a short c program. In `nix-repl`

```
simple = derivation { name = "simple"; builder = "${bash}/bin/bash"; args = [ ./simple_builder.sh ]; gcc = gcc; coreutils = coreutils; src = ./simple.c; system = builtins.currentSystem; }
:b simple
```

compiles the source and makes the output-directory containing the `simple`-executable.

If the c-source changes a bit, say, we want to output "Simple?", the same derivation simple with same arguments doesn't seem to work.

Why is that and does it mean, that even for minor changes in c-file a new name (?) -argument has to be given for the derivation?

If so, how to get rid of the old derivations made within nix-repl with `:b adrvn`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?   Did you try re-running the long line of code that defines `simple`?

Comment: Yes, that re-running didn't change work (it seems it requires re-start of nix-repl). I got uncertain about this while trying out different things to learn the nix-lang. Emmanuel Rosa gave the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `simple` is a value/constant rather than a function. Given that Nix is purely functional, it doesn't matter how many times you evaluate `simple` it will always produce the same output (within the same instance of `nix-repl`). On the other hand, going with an external file (ex. simple.nix) and using `nix-build` will pick up changes to the derivation's inputs, including `simple.c`.

As for cleaning up derivations, you can use `nix-collect-garbage`.